# Python code for Insertion sort taking input as a string value

Tags: python, python-2.7

This Python code gives sorted elements according to string elements.
How we convert list elements, which are in string format in integer type?

This is my code:

```
def insertionSort(arr, n):
for i in range(1, n):
    key = arr[i]
    j = i - 1
    while j >= 0 and arr[j] > key:
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]
        j = j - 1
    arr[j+1] = key
print '\nSorted elements: ',    
return (' ').join(arr)

arr = (raw_input("enter elements: ")).split(',')  
print insertionSort(arr, len(arr))
```

Comment: you mean testing like this: `int(arr[j]) > int(key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to convert your elements using a element to key function so you can use comparison not of the element itself but of a transformed data suiting your needs.

I would do this as a generic solution:

```
def insertionSort(arr, n, keyfunc=lambda x:x):
    for i in range(1, n):
        key = arr[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and keyfunc(arr[j]) > keyfunc(key):
            arr[j+1] = arr[j]
            j = j - 1
        arr[j+1] = key
    return ' '.join(arr)
```

so by default, the key is just the element itself, but if you call your function like this:

```
insertionSort(arr, len(arr), keyfunc=int)
```

the key function is now "conversion to integer", and sorting works as expected on a list of integers as strings.

(note that the built-in `sort` method works that way, by allowing to provide a `key` function).

of course you can drop the whole `keyfunc` idea and just hardcode `int` here:

```
while j >= 0 and int(arr[j]) > int(key):
```